# How to secure my app that working over MySQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net, security

I have an application doing things on MySQL. I made it with VB.NET and with standart MySQL library. My question is, is it easy to hack? Can even basic hackers reach my database? And how can i secure it?

Thank you.

Comment: I have  piece of string, how long is it? Please check [ask] and provide a [mcve]. A specific question with code is more likely to get an answer.

Comment: It’s more like a general quesion about MySQL connection security. Because I didn’t do any extra thing to secure the connection. I’m using the default functions like mysql_connect, or someting like it. Additionally I’m holding the credentials on some variables.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should never save your Passwords in MYSQL_PWD environment. Because there might be a possibility in some versions of "ps" which can show/expose the password clearly to some other user.
2. Access to the database tables should be restricted to only those who are required to access data from them, otherwise it must not be accessed by some other user.
3. Automatic Password expiration technique must be up (Usually it's duration is set to 6 months or 180 days).
4. Sometimes the passwords are sent in a plain text in SQL Queries like Set password etc.
5. You must usually check the Privileges given to the users and you must use Revoke command to remove unnecessary privileges given to the users.
6. A Firewall must be installed before the MYSQL Database layer.

I think this answer helped you with your question somewhere.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. My method is, i have a class which holds some variables I use within the application runtime (like db name, pass, username, host etc.). Then when forms loaded, I connect to MySQL with mysql_connect function, with the variables i have in the class. Is it a risky way to work? When I release the app I’m gonna obfuscate it for decryption of course.